# Chrome tab rearrangement stopped working after upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 21.10

Tags: google-chrome, 21.10

Over the last month I updated 2 machines from Kubuntu 20.04 LTS to 21.10. The only problem I've run into so far is that Chrome tabs are not allowing me to rearrange the order or to recombine 2 browser windows back into one. If I left click on a tab in a group of 4 tabs and try to move it then I immediately get a new browser window with only that tab. If I attempt to reintegrate this browser window back into the group of now 3 tabs it won't combine.

Is this a known problem that I'm just not finding the right search terms for? Both machines show the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Appears to be a real thing:

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/144283617/i-can-t-move-tabs-in-my-chrome?hl=en

Comment: There is no *supported* upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.10; so how did you upgrade?   Currently the only *supported* upgrade path from 20.04 is to 21.04 (which isn't EOL yet; though will be in a few days, **then** upgrade will switch from to 21.10).   I'd check you didn't *introduce* issues given you're not using Ubuntu *release-upgrade* tools (*it may not be this; but elsewhere too!*)

Comment: One machine was 20.04->21.04->21.10, the laptop was a new 21.10 install. Both run KDE, both have the same problem. But of course the link I provided above shows other people having the same issue so I'll wait and watch how others are solving it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, and according to [this article](https://piunikaweb.com/2022/01/15/google-chrome-97-tab-drag-drop-or-move-issue-officially-acknowledged/), a bug fix is on the way.

In the meantime, you may be able to resolve the issue by changing in Chrome's *Settings* → *Appearance* → *Use system title bar and borders* to *Off*.

Comment: I found this solution here (official bug tracker): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224606#c42

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed in Chrome 97.0.4692.99